# C# connected to SQL not returning a value

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection

I connected to SQL Server with C#. Now, I have to do 3 options. One is to execute a procedure, which works perfectly, the second one is to retrieve some data, which is also done and the last option is to select a specific country, which is chosen by the user, and show an average of the scores of the restaurants that are located in that country.

Now, the query works on SSMS as I tested it. However, when I tried to run it like the other 2 options, it gave me a connection error.

The code below is the C# code of the second option that works:

```
public static void showStatistics()
{
    string connetionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-RV4VR9I;Initial 
Catalog=Assignment;User ID=Jake;Password=1234;Integrated Security=True";

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
    SqlCommand mySQL = new SqlCommand("BEGIN TRANSACTION SET     
TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED SELECT TOP 1 country, score, 
year FROM main.[stats] ORDER BY [Statistics Generated] DESC COMMIT         
TRANSACTION", conn);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        SqlDataReader dataReader = mySQL.ExecuteReader();

        string holderCountry = "";
        string holderScore = "";
        string holderYear = "";

        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
             holderCountry += dataReader["country"];
             holderScore += dataReader["score"];
             holderYear += dataReader["year"];
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nCountry: "+holderCountry);
        Console.WriteLine("Score: " + holderScore);
        Console.WriteLine("Year: " + holderYear+"\n");

        conn.Close();
    }    
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Can not open connection ! ");
    }
}
```

The next chunk of code is the code that is giving me an error:

```
public static void showCountryAverage(string countryChoice)
        {
            string connetionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-RV4VR9I;Initial 
Catalog=Assignment;User ID=Jake;Password=1234;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            SqlCommand mySQL = new SqlCommand("BEGIN TRANSACTION SET 
TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED SELECT c.country, 
AVG(CAST(re.score AS DECIMAL(8, 6))) FROM main.country c JOIN 
main.restaurant r ON(c.countryId = r.countryId) JOIN main.review re 
ON(r.restaurantId = re.restaurantId) WHERE c.country = "+countryChoice+" 
GROUP BY c.country COMMIT TRANSACTION", conn);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader dataReader = mySQL.ExecuteReader();
                string holderCountry = "";
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {

                    holderCountry += dataReader["country"];
                    holderCountry += dataReader["AVG(CAST(re.score AS     
DECIMAL(8, 6)))"];
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\nCountry: " + holderCountry);
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Can not open connection ! ");
            }
        }
```

Thanks!

This is the error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'Italy'.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
>      at Database_Number_6.Program.showCountryAverage(String countryChoice) in C:\Users\User\Desktop\000SWD6.1B\2ndSemester\Database 2\Assignment\Database_Number_6\Database_Number_6\Program.cs:line 133
>   ClientConnectionId:74fbcdc0-47ec-41cc-839d-0b05b13661df
>   Error Number:207,State:1,Class:16

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: What is the reasong for those BEGIN TRANSACTION etc on some SELECT query?

Comment: @SLaks its a really long error but the first part says "Invalid column name"

Comment: @Steve the reason is that it is an assignment and requires us to use transactions

Comment: Post the entire error message in your question.

Comment: You need to create an alias for the column (using `as`); expressions in `SELECT` queries do not become column names.

Comment: I tried adding the alias to the AVG but it still doesn't work.. NB: On sql it works WITHOUT an alias..

Comment: You cannot just dump T-SQL from your SQL Studio Query Window to an SQLCommand ... Well, you _can_ but don't expect it to _work_.

Comment: it's my first time connecting to a database using C#, so I might be doing some mistakes. However, as i mentioned before, the other 2 queries work perfectly.

Comment: Is your variable _countryChoice_  equals to _Italy_?

Comment: Yes, I am asking the user in the main class and passing the variable as a parameter, aka countryChoice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem *Invalid column name Italy* is caused by your concatenation of the string *Italy* to your sql command. In SQL, if you want to express a constant string value, you should put it between single quotes like *'Italy'*. Without the quotes the sql parser engine thinks that you want to compare the values in the *country* column with the values in a *Italy* column. So, adding quotes can resolve the problem, but this is a well known source of parsing bugs (what if the value contains itself a single quote? and I don't even start to talk about dates) Worse this approach allows an easy way to hack a database through [Sql Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-2017).

The only correct way to create queries that needs code's values is using parameters

```
SqlCommand mySQL = new SqlCommand(@".....
                                   SELECT c.country, 
                                   ....
                                   FROM main.country c 
                                   ....
                                   WHERE c.country = @country
                                   GROUP BY .....", con);
mySql.Parameters.Add("@country", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = countryCode;
 ....
```

Comment: Thanks Steve! I just fixed it and it's slightly different than yours, though it's pretty much the same! Thanks again